# Angular UI-view - How to deallocate HTML & scope of last view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, memory-leaks

I have single page application developed using AngularJS. I am using ui routing to load different views.

I facing memory leak issue in the application. On using chrome profiling tool it seems like when user navigate from one view to another view then it is not deallocating HTML of first view.

Can anybody please tell me how I can deallocate memory for HTML  (& possibly its controller as well) of last view which gets unloaded.

Atul Sureka

Comment: You mean that switching between state1 and state2 20 times continuously increase memory consumption?

Comment: Yes, when I switch b/t states memory consumption is keep on increasing

Comment: Can be a lot of reasons for this. Angular removes only DOM elements and its scopes. I.e. if in controler you have: $rootScope.$watch/$parent.$watch - you need to remove this manually on scope destroy. (Same for $intervals, win.bind, ...)